# Plot Highcharts data from past 30 days with Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out the best way to expose the data I need from the Rails back-end to the front-end to plot data from the past 30 days, regardless if an entry was recorded on every day of those past 30 days or not.

My controller code looks like so:

```
@symptoms = @current_member.symptoms

@symptoms_array ||= []

@symptoms.each do |symptom|
    array = [ Time.parse(symptom.date).getutc.iso8601, symptom.level.to_i ]
    @symptoms_array.push(array)
end
```

In my view I'm just throwing that data into a `data` attribute on an element to read with JS (I know, there's better ways to do this...).

`<div id="graph" class="graph" data-symptoms="<%= @symptoms_array %>">`

And then my Highcharts JS instantiation looks like this:

```
const data = $('#graph').data('symptoms');

Highcharts.chart('graph', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        title: 'Pain levels'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Pain level'
        },
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        tickInterval: 1
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.y}'
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Pain level',
        data: data
    }]
});
```

What I need is for the chart to display the symptoms from every day in the past 30 days, regardless if there was an entry that day or not (it should just display a 0 for days without entries). And the X axis should show M...F in correlation with the day of the week. Right now, with the hardcoded array, it just shows M, T, W, T, F, S, S, 7, 8, 9, 10, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider: the array will need to have all dates, including the ones with no data and each date will need to be in the appropriate format; so i'll do the following:

1. Update the controller to return a hash (instead of an array).
2. Create *helper* method to create the `data_series` array.
3. Use `label` instead of `categories` in the chart.

#### Controller

Create a hash to store the values, where each key is the `date` (in `Date` format) and its value is the `level`:

```
def action
  @symptoms_hash = @current_member.symptoms.each do |symptom|
    date = Time.parse(symptom.date).getutc.iso8601.to_date
    symptoms_hash[date] = symptom.level.to_i
  end
end
```

Notice the added `.to_date`, this will allow us to easier convert the date to javascript format.

#### Helper

```
def data_series(symptoms_hash)
  dates = (symptoms_hash.keys.min..symptoms_hash.keys.max).to_a

  dates.map do |date, value|
    js_date = "Date.UTC(#{date.year}, #{date.month - 1}, #{date.day})"
    "[#{js_date}, #{symptoms_hash[date].to_i}]"
  end
end
```

A few notes to understand better:

- `dates` represent the time range to be plotted, and gets its first and last date from the minimum and maximum dates in `symptoms_hash`.
- `Date.UTC` is used to create a valid *javascript* date so *highcharts* can recognize it as *date*, which will let us get the matching *day of week*.
- `date.month - 1` is used because months in javascript start with `0` you need to substract `1` to the date's month, otherwise you'll get the wrong date.
- The return value is an array of strings, but we will turn it into an array of arrays in the view.

#### View

Set `data` using the helper that was just created and replace `categories` with `labels`, which will need a custom `formatter` to display the first letter in the name of the day of week name.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const data = [<%= data_series(@symptoms_hash).join(",") %>];

  Highcharts.chart('graph', {
      chart: {
          type: 'column',
          title: 'Pain levels'
      },
      xAxis: {
          type: 'datetime',
          labels: {
            formatter: function() {
              var dayOfWeek   = Highcharts.dateFormat('%A', this.value);
              var firstLetter = dayOfWeek.substring(0, 1);
              return firstLetter;
          }
          },
          title: {
              text: 'Date'
          }
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Pain level'
          },
          min: 0,
          max: 10,
          tickInterval: 1
      },
      tooltip: {
          headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
          pointFormat: '{point.y}'
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'Pain level',
          data: data
      }]
  });
</script>
```

Notice the `join` when setting `data`, it is used to create the array of arrays needed for the chart `series` to work.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `groupdate` gem (https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) in combination with `chartkick` (https://github.com/ankane/chartkick).
In your case you can simply use something like:

```
@symptoms = current_user.symptoms.group_by_day(:created_at).count
```

to have all symptoms aggregated by day. And then plot them with, for example:

```
<%= column_chart @symptoms %>
```

Look at the gems documentation for further examples.